# Query Returns Result But status still shows Retrieving Column Remarks on SQL Workbench Vertica

Tags: sql, database, vertica, workbench

I'm trying to run SQL simple direct SELECT query on SQL Workbench (Attaching Images). (Using Vertica 11)

The results are returned but status in bottom left corner displays **Retrieving Column Remarks...** and takes almost 2 min to finish. During the "Retrieving column remarks" I cannot edit the SQL script on page.

[Retrieving column remarks...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4pK0P.png)

Tried to Google for solutions.

Looks to me it depends on some system related command.

Usually the query should take 1 sec to return results.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Disabled the option "Retrieve column remarks for queries]

Disabled the option "Retrieve column remarks for queries"

Disabled the option "Retrieve column remarks for queries"

Answer (score -1):

The `"Retrieving Column Remarks"` message in SQL Workbench indicates that the tool is retrieving the comments that have been defined for the columns in the table that you are querying. This can be a time-consuming process, especially if there are a lot of columns or if the comments are long.

There are a few things you can do to speed up the process:

- Disable the retrieval of column remarks. To do this, open the SQL Workbench preferences dialog and go to the "Advanced" tab. In the "Retrieval of extended properties" section, uncheck the "Retrieve remarks for tables and columns" checkbox.
- Use a different JDBC driver. Some JDBC drivers are faster than others at retrieving column remarks. You can try using a different driver to see if it makes a difference.
- Index the columns. Indexes can help to speed up queries by making it easier for the database server to find the data that you are looking for. If you are querying columns that are not indexed, you can try indexing them to see if it improves the performance.